# jsonResponse = r.json() NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to pull some data from the official EPL Premier League Fantasy Football website but having trouble with `jsonResponse`.

Tried installing simplejson `pip install simplejson`

Not sure what else to try, see my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Define a function to get info from the FPL API and save to the specified file_path
# It might be a good idea to navigate to the link in a browser to get an idea of what the data looks like

def get_json(file_path): r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/')
jsonResponse = r.json()
with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile: json.dump(jsonResponse, outfile)

# Run the function and choose where to save the json file
get_json('C:\Ste Files\Python\test\fpl.json')

# Open the json file and print a list of the keys

with open('C:\Ste Files\Python\test\fpl.json') as json_data: d = json.load(json_data)
print(list(d.keys()))
```

I expect a file to be written to the path in code. But I'm getting the following error:

```
(base) C:\Ste File\Python\test>python ste_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ste_test.py", line 10, in <module>
jsonResponse = r.json()
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

Comment: Given the error I don't think the indentation problems here are just failure to post correctly. That line is probably *outside* the function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: If this is exactly your code in your ide, it fails because of its indention is missing. python needs proper indention. Have a look at some tutorials first

Comment: You probably just need to properly indent your get_json function's lines of code.

Comment: indentation matters. your `r.json()` is not within the scope of the `get_json` function (because of improper indenting), hence, the name `r` is undefined.

Comment: The indentation has fixed one error, but I still have another. Can anyone get this to work?

` (base) C:\>cd C:\Ste Files\Python\test

(base) C:\Ste Files\Python\test>python ste_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ste_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    get_json('C:\Ste Files\Python\test\fpl.json')
  File "ste_test.py", line 12, in get_json
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Ste Files\\Python\test\x0cpl.json' `

Answer (score 0):

the [indentation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) may trick you :

change your code:

```
def get_json(file_path): r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/')
jsonResponse = r.json()
with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile: json.dump(jsonResponse, outfile)
```

with:

```
def get_json(file_path):
    r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/')
    jsonResponse = r.json()
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile: 
        json.dump(jsonResponse, outfile)
```

or:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os 

dir_path = os.getcwd()

json_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'fpl.json')


# Define a function to get info from the FPL API and save to the specified file_path
# It might be a good idea to navigate to the link in a browser to get an idea of what the data looks like

def get_json(file_path):
    r = requests.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/')
    jsonResponse = r.json()
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile: 
        json.dump(jsonResponse, outfile)

# Run the function and choose where to save the json file
get_json(json_path)

# Open the json file and print a list of the keys

with open(json_path) as json_data:
   d = json.load(json_data)

print(list(d.keys()))
# output: ['events', 'game_settings', 'phases', 'teams', 'total_players', 'elements', 'element_stats', 'element_types']
```

Comment: The indentation has fixed one error, but I still have another. Can anyone get this to work? 
```python
(base) C:\>cd C:\Ste Files\Python\test 
(base) C:\Ste Files\Python\test>python ste_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "ste_test.py", line 16, in <module> 
get_json('C:\Ste Files\Python\test\fpl.json') 
File "ste_test.py", line 12, in get_json 
with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile: 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Ste Files\\Python\test\x0cpl.json' ```

Comment: you could use instead of string 'C:\Ste Files\Python\test\fpl.json  a variable  json_path
: import os 
dir_path = os.getcwd()

json_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'fpl.json')
json_path

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant! That works a treat. Only think I need to figure out now is how to extract the player data. Season starts Friday eeeeeek

Comment: I did upvote. I have <15 rep so won't show publicly

Comment: Can I help with something more or this question is close?